# Finding the grade based on the best score

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

So my program wants the user to input the number of students and their scores. Based on the best score it will follow this grading scheme:

1. The score is > or = the best - 10 then the grade is A.
2. The score is > or = the best - 20 then the grade is B.
3. The score is > or = the best - 30 then the grade is C.
4. The score is > or = the best - 40 then the grade is D.
5. Anything else is an F

This is my code so far:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync')


let scoreArray = []
let best = 0

students = readlineSync.question('Enter the number of students: ');

for (var x = 0; x < students; x++){
 score = readlineSync.question('Enter Score: ')
 scoreArray.push(score);
}

for (var i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++){
   var data = scoreArray[i];
   if(best < scoreArray[i]){
   best = scoreArray[i];
 }
   if(scoreArray[i] >= (best-10)){
     grade = 'A';
   }else if(scoreArray[i] >= (best-20)){
     grade = 'B';
   }else if(scoreArray[i] >= (best-30)){
     grade = 'C';
   }else if(scoreArray[i] >= (best-40)){
     grade = 'D';
   }else {
     grade = 'F';
  }
 console.log('Student ' + i + ' score is ' + scoreArray[i] +' and grade is ' +   grade);

 }
```

When I run the code it sometimes displays the correct grade and sometimes it doesn't.  It should display this:

---

- Enter the number of students: 4
- Enter Score: 40
- Enter Score: 55
- Enter Score: 70
- Enter Score: 58
- Student 0 score is 40 and grade is C. Student 1 score is 55 and grade
  is B. Student 2 score is 70 and grade is A. Student 3 score is 58 and
  grade is B.

Instead it displays the grades A,A,A,B.

Comment: As a caution on what comparison operators return on boolean with strings, I'd convert my `readlineSync` inputs to `int` before operating on them. E.g. `students = parseInt(students)`, `score = parseInt(score)`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're iterating over `scoreArray` and updating best along the way. You should first get the max score from `scoreArray` so you know the best to start with, and then iterate over `scoreArray`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max for more info, but put `var best = Math.max(...scoreArray);` before your for loop, and then your conditional logic should work.

```js
scoreArray = [49, 81, 72, 80, 81, 36, 58];
var best = Math.max(...scoreArray);

for (var i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
  var data = scoreArray[i];

  if (scoreArray[i] >= (best - 10)) {
    grade = 'A';
  } else if (scoreArray[i] >= (best - 20)) {
    grade = 'B';
  } else if (scoreArray[i] >= (best - 30)) {
    grade = 'C';
  } else if (scoreArray[i] >= (best - 40)) {
    grade = 'D';
  } else {
    grade = 'F';
  }

  console.log('Student ' + i + ' score is ' + scoreArray[i] + ' and grade is ' + grade);

}
```